# Access low byte of dptr on Intel 8031

Tags: 8051

Is there a way to access the low/high bytes of `dptr` individually when programming for the Intel 8031/8051 Microprocessor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out.  The register names are `dpl` and `dph`.